# 2005 Mercury Montaego won't start.

Tags: cranks-wont-run, mercury

While driving, it started stuttering like it wasn't getting any gas. Had to tow it home. Changed fuel pump, fuel rail pressure sensor.  Got it to start 1 time, buy wont again.
 Battery stays dead. While trying to start it. The radio, CD player & guages flicker off & on  & up and down. I noticed the inside lights were still on when they should've cut off already.   Then they flickered on and off 3 to 4 times along with this blue light on the outside driver door near the rear veiw mirror I've never seen before. After that I noticed the interior lights for the gauges  weře still on. With no key in the ignition, all lights were off & doors shut.  We haven't done anything else to it. ODG2 meter only read the fuel rail pressure sensor but pending.  That's why we changed it.  Please help !

Comment: This generation of Fords had lots of issues with water intrusion that causes strange electrical problems. Check all the interior and exterior fuse boxes for water. Was it raining when the car first acted up?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!